# Table thumbnail_kvstore doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I can't get the thumbnail displayed in my template. I get this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'ia_website.thumbnail_kvstore' doesn't exist")

- Installed sorl_thumbnail-12.3
- I'm using MariaDB 10.1.11
- I have no migration that are not executed
- I can see the image if I don't use the 'thumbnail' tag

Here is what I did

- In settings.py:

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
      'sorl.thumbnail',
  ]

  THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = TRUE
  ```
- In models.py

  ```
  import sorl
  ...
      image = sorl.thumbnail.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails', null=True)
  ```
- In my template

  ```
  {% thumbnail content.image "237x110" as im %}
      <img src="{{ im.url }}">
  {% endthumbnail %}
  ```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So after some research, it looks like the version `12.3` of sorl-thumbnail on PyPI and Github are different!

If you download the source directly from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorl-thumbnail/12.3) - you will find that the package doesn't contain any migrations. **This is the reason the table doesn't exist even though you've run all the migrations**.

On Github, [the migration file](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/blob/v12.3/sorl/thumbnail/migrations/0001_initial.py) for version `12.3` definitely exists.

You have three options:

1. Create the table using `./manage.py syncdb` (only if you're running Django 1.8 or below)
2. Install directly from Github for version `12.3`
3. Use version `12.4a1` of sorl-thumbnail which includes migrations

You can install from Github directly as follows:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail@v12.3
```

sorl-thumbnail version 12.3 supports up to Django version 1.8, where the syncdb command still exists. If you're running Django 1.8 or lower, you can create the missing table by running

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: Ok thanks this works. As I am using Django 1.9.1 I ran ./manage.py migrate after having installed the version 12.3 from git.

Comment: Please see answer from AlmasK89 below for running makemigrations in Django 1.9 or higher: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35883910/568270

Answer (score 53):

If just

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

doesn't create any migrations, try

```
manage.py makemigrations thumbnail 
manage.py migrate
```

This will create migrations for thumbnail and then migrate them. 
It works for me. 
I am using Django 1.9 and sorl.thumbnail 12.3.

Comment: I cannot find this in the documentation - but it works

Comment: You can read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps
and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations
Shortly, we use application label to show django from what application migrations must be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Use version 12.3 of sorl-thumbnail. Follow this steps

Remove actual version

```
pip uninstall sorl-thumbnail
```

Install version 12.3

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail@v12.3
```

Migrations

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the error just occurred while executing `dumpdata`.

So if you find this thread here because you tried to use `dumpdata`, then excluding the thumbnail app will probably be an easy workaround for you:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude thumbnail
```

Of course you should follow the other answers, if you want to have your Django clean.

Comment: this one is useful for a quick test when you don't want to run migrations, etc