# django sorl-thumbnail doesn't work even very simple example

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

Env : `Max OSX 10` ,`Python3.5`, `Django 1.10`

I exactly follow below things,

1. `pip install sorl-thumbnail`
2. Add `sorl.thumbnail` to my `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`
3. `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate <my_app>`

And my very very simple template :

```
{% extends 'chacha_dabang/skeleton/base.html' %}

{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}

{% thumbnail "http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/abend.jpg" "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}

{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't even work!

When I check html elements through `Chrome development tool`, no `img` tag at all! Only my `base.html` elements exists....

Anything that I missed?

Comment: Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136411/table-thumbnail-kvstore-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is that you have not installed Pillow? As its said [there](https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements.html) sorl.thumbnail has requirements to work correctly. I'd user Pillow, don't forget to add 'PIL' to your installed apps.